# Remix - cant compile for unknown reason

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, javascript, contract-debugging

When I compile the program it says it's expecting a ; somewhere in line 8.

I've tried adding it in, getting rid of brackets in the line where it's telling me to, but with no avail.

Be great if you could help me out please.

Regards,
New to solidity person

```
contract SimpleStorage {

    //this will get init to 0
    uint256 public favoriteNumber;
    
    functon store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

}
```

Comment: ```functon``` -> ```function```

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `function`.

```
contract SimpleStorage {

    //this will get init to 0
    uint256 public favoriteNumber;
    
    function store(uint256 _favoriteNumber) public {
        favoriteNumber = _favoriteNumber;
    }

}
```

On to the next issue.

Hope it helps.